# If $b_i$ is a base of $F_i$ and $F = F_1 \oplus \dots \oplus F_n$ then the concatenation of $b_i$ forms a base of $F$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $E$ be a vector space, and $F_i$, $1\leq i \leq s$ subspaces of $E$ of dimension $n_i$ and $b_i = (e_{i,1}, \dots, e_{i,n_i})$ a base of $F_i$ and $F = F_1 \oplus \dots \oplus F_n$. Show that the concatenation of $b_i$ forms a base of $F$ and that $\dim F = \sum n_i = \sum \dim F_i$.

My attempt:

Let $u \in F$. Then $u = f_1 + \dots +f_s$ with $f_i = \lambda_{i,1}e_{i,1} + \dots + \lambda_{i,n_i}e_{i,n_i}$.

Thus $$u = \lambda_{1,1}e_{1,1} + \dots + \lambda_{1,n_i}e_{1,n_i}  + \dots \dots \dots  + \lambda_{s,1}e_{s,1} + \dots + \lambda_{s,n_i}e_{s,n_i}$$

$u$ is written in a unique way using $f_i$ who themselves are written in a unique way using the elements of the basis $b_i$. Thus the concatenation of the $b_i$ forms a basis of $F$. And so we have $\dim F = {\rm card}\,(b) = \sum \dim(b_i)$.

Is my approach correct? I am rather really unsure.

Comment: Even though I would personally be convinced by your argument here, I think it would be better to show things more carefully if you are taking an elementary course of linear algebra right now. Namely, in this case, one would expect two parts in your proof, first show that your family is generating (you did it), then show that it is free (you kind of justified it, but did not actually prove it). 
Because I can feel you are understanding the situation well, I am sure that proving freeness will be no problem for you.

Comment: It's "basis", not "base".